# How to install pandas library in QGIS python?

Tags: python, pandas, qgis

I'm building a `QGIS plugin` and using Python `Pandas` library. How to install Pandas library in QGIS python? Please help me !

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Check this [site](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134267/how-do-i-install-a-external-package-in-qgis)

Comment: This could be tricky as QGIS python isn't up to date. But try this, I installed PySAL library with the step by step guide. [Check this guide](http://umar-yusuf.blogspot.com.ng/2016/07/How-to-Install-Third-party-Python-Modules-in-QGIS-Windows.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways:

1. Install `pip` for your version of Python:
   https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html

   $ wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
   $ sudo python get-pip.py

Then install `pandas`: `$ sudo pip install pandas`

2. Install pandas from source:
   http://pandas.pydata.org/getpandas.html
   compile it and copy the package to your `PYTHON_PATH`.

Comment: Thanks luart, 

I'm using QGIS on windows, not linux. Can you guide with windows ?

Comment: There is no difference when you install modules in Python using pip, because Python code is cross-platform and C libs are compiled from source.
So it should work as describe above, you just should download the `get-pip.py` using some browser instead of the `wget` and have some C compiler (VC or etc.)
See details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows
`sudo` should be just omitted, i.e. use `python get-pip.py` and `pip install pandas` from Windows terminal (your python should be in the system PATH).

Answer (score 0):

- Navigate to `C:\QGIS\apps\Python27\` or `C:\QGIS\apps\Python37`.
- Right click while  holding `shift` and open command prompt or powershell here.
- Type `python -m pip install pandas`.